# How to allow AutoGPT to install dependencies?

Tags: autogpt

I've been able to let AutoGPT access to a python script and I want it to fill in the script and evaluate the results and update but it returns errors saying some packages are missing and cannot install (restrictions of current environment) I've already added the following lines to .env

```
RESTRICT_TO_WORKSPACE=False
EXECUTE_LOCAL_COMMANDS=True
```

but still not working, any help is appreciated!